# Вернуть сумму диапазона чисел

Tags: python, математика

Есть такая задача:
Для двух данных целых чисел `a` и `b`, которые могут быть положительными или отрицательными, найдите и верните сумму всех целых чисел между ними, включая сами эти числа.
Если два числа равны, верните `a` или `b`.
Должен получиться такой вывод:

```
(1, 0) --> 1 (1 + 0 = 1)
(1, 2) --> 3 (1 + 2 = 3)
(0, 1) --> 1 (0 + 1 = 1)
(1, 1) --> 1 (1 since both are same)
(-1, 0) --> -1 (-1 + 0 = -1)
(-1, 2) --> 2 (-1 + 0 + 1 + 2 = 2)
```

Код:

```py
def get_sum(a, b):
    return a if a == b else sum(range(a, b + 1))
```

Не могу понять, как верно учесть этот нюанс?  Можно ли учесть его с помощью `elif` в этой же строке? Возможно есть более красивое решение? Буду очень благодарен вашим ответам.

Comment: «как верно учесть этот ньюанс?» — какой? Код `sum(range(a, b + 1))` корректно работает для всех приведённых вами примеров (даже проверка `a == b` здесь не нужна), а если `b` окажется меньше чем `a`, то достаточно просто поменять их местами

Comment: для суммы такого ряда есть формула `(a+b)/2 * (b-a+1)`

Answer (score 1):

Задача решена

```
def get_sum(a, b):
    if a == b: 
        return a
    elif a < b:
        return sum(range(a, b + 1))
    else:
        return sum(range(b, a + 1))
```

Comment: 1) `elif` и `else` не нужны. 2) `if a==b: return a` тоже не нужен

Answer (score 0):

Можно суммировать `range` от минимума до максимума:

```
def get_sum(a, b):
    return sum(range(min(a, b), max(a, b) + 1))


print(get_sum(*map(int, input().split())))
```

Но простота имеет свою цену. Время суммирования пропорционально разнице *b - a*:

> ```
> $ time echo 0 10_000_000 | python get_sum.py
> 50000005000000
>
> real  0m0.204s
> user  0m0.204s
> sys   0m0.000s
>
> $ time echo 0 100_000_000 | python get_sum.py
> 5000000050000000
>
> real  0m1.796s
> user  0m1.788s
> sys   0m0.004s
>
> $ time echo 0 1_000_000_000 | python get_sum.py
> 500000000500000000
>
> real  0m17.354s
> user  0m17.344s
> sys   0m0.004s
> ```

`range` - по сути арифметическая прогрессия. А для её суммы есть [формула](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D1%82_n-%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%BE_m-%D0%B3%D0%BE):

```
def get_sum(a, b):
    return (a + b) * (abs(a - b) + 1) // 2


print(get_sum(*map(int, input().split())))
```

Время перестало расти (почти):

> ```
> $ time echo 0 1_000_000_000 | python get_sum.py
> 500000000500000000
>
> real  0m0.031s
> user  0m0.024s
> sys   0m0.004s
>
> $ time echo 0 1_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000 | python get_sum.py
> 500000000000000000000000000500000000000000000000000000
>
> real  0m0.030s
> user  0m0.028s
> sys   0m0.000s
> ```